# Lubuntu: connect to Huawei E3531

Tags: 16.04, udev, usb-modem

After hours of trying searching the web and trying several things, I can't get running a Huawei E3531 usb-modem.
Before updating Lubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS it worked well. Now it noticed the following:
- udev-rules are the same as before
- it seems, as if the mode of the usb-stick is already "modem" and no more mass storage.
- Internet doesn't appear anymore in network-manager

Here are the logs:

**lsusb** right after plug-in:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:15d2 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

**lsusb** a moment later:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:15d3 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

**/etc/udev/rules.d/70-usb-modeswitch.rules**:

```
# my own rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="15d2", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 15d2 -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="15d3", RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'modprobe option && echo 12d1 15d3 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id'"
```

**usb_modeswitch**:

```
$usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 15d3 -M
Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 007 on bus 001
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
Use endpoints 0x02 (out) and 0x82 (in)
Error: can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0;
       interface class is 255, expected 8. Abort
```

**tail -f /var/log/syslog**

```
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  217.772449] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 4
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  217.772756] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  217.772785] option 1-3:1.0: device disconnected
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  217.772905] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-3:1.1 wwx001e101f0000: unregister 'huawei_cdc_ncm' usb-0000:00:1d.7-3, Huawei CDC NCM device
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  217.788591] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  217.788621] option 1-3:1.2: device disconnected
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  217.788801] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  217.788827] option 1-3:1.3: device disconnected
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 udisksd[1307]: Cleaning up mount point /media/elisabeth/MDM_2.1_MCM_3.05 (device 11:1 no longer exist)
Feb 17 16:31:16 Inspiron-5100 NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1518881476.8835] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/net/wwx001e101f0000, iface: wwx001e101f0000)
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  227.848049] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  227.987447] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=15d2
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  227.987454] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  227.987458] usb 1-3: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  227.987461] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  227.987464] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  228.065619] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  228.066100] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3"
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Feb 17 16:31:26 Inspiron-5100 systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch_1-3:1.0...
Feb 17 16:31:27 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  228.215024] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 5
Feb 17 16:31:27 Inspiron-5100 systemd[1]: usb_modeswitch@1-3:1.0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 17 16:31:27 Inspiron-5100 systemd[1]: Failed to start USB_ModeSwitch_1-3:1.0.
Feb 17 16:31:27 Inspiron-5100 systemd[1]: usb_modeswitch@1-3:1.0.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 17 16:31:27 Inspiron-5100 systemd[1]: usb_modeswitch@1-3:1.0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 17 16:31:28 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.112027] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.245227] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=15d3
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.245235] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.245239] usb 1-3: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.245243] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.245246] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.601930] option 1-3:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.602143] usb 1-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.602641] option 1-3:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.602847] option 1-3:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.603021] usb 1-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.603189] option 1-3:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.603336] usb 1-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.606663] usb-storage 1-3:1.4: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.607844] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-3:1.4
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.608268] usb-storage 1-3:1.5: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  230.610182] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-3:1.5
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3"
Feb 17 16:31:29 Inspiron-5100 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.621462] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.621700] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.625333] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.626954] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.634674] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.635020] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.635327] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.746487] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.746502] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.746508] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.746516] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 ff fe 00 00 02 00
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.746521] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 262136
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.752721] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.752733] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.752741] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.752748] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 ff fe 00 00 02 00
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.752753] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 262136
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.752761] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 32767, async page read
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.914234] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.914246] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.914253] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.914260] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 ff fc 00 00 02 00
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.914265] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 262128
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.924356] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.924368] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.924375] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.924381] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 ff fc 00 00 02 00
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.924387] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 262128
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  231.924394] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 32766, async page read
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  232.016389] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 kernel: [  232.016764] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
Feb 17 16:31:30 Inspiron-5100 udisksd[1307]: Mounted /dev/sr1 at /media/elisabeth/MDM_2.1_MCM_3.05 on behalf of uid 1000
Feb 17 16:31:45 Inspiron-5100 ntpd[1202]: bind(27) AF_INET6 2a02:1205:c6bd:470:7d84:5dbe:8e8b:9530#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Feb 17 16:31:45 Inspiron-5100 ntpd[1202]: unable to create socket on eth0 (8) for 2a02:1205:c6bd:470:7d84:5dbe:8e8b:9530#123
Feb 17 16:31:45 Inspiron-5100 ntpd[1202]: failed to init interface for address 2a02:1205:c6bd:470:7d84:5dbe:8e8b:9530
Feb 17 16:31:45 Inspiron-5100 avahi-daemon[579]: Registering new address record for 2a02:1205:c6bd:470:7d84:5dbe:8e8b:9530 on eth0.*.
Feb 17 16:31:47 Inspiron-5100 ntpd[1202]: Listen normally on 9 eth0 [2a02:1205:c6bd:470:7d84:5dbe:8e8b:9530]:123
Feb 17 16:31:47 Inspiron-5100 ntpd[1202]: 2001:67c:1560:8003::c8 local addr 2a02:1205:c6bd:470:7c90:f75c:1384:d766 -> 2a02:1205:c6bd:470:7d84:5dbe:8e8b:9530
Feb 17 16:31:47 Inspiron-5100 ntpd[1202]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Feb 17 16:32:15 Inspiron-5100 systemd[817]: Time has been changed
Feb 17 16:32:15 Inspiron-5100 systemd[1]: Time has been changed
```

So my question is: What can I do to get the usb-modem running? If you need any additional logs, please tell me.

EDIT:
"solved" it by reinstalling Lubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try the following: disconnect your modem, open terminal and run command `tail -f /var/log/syslog` then insert modem and wait for its initialization (about 1 minute), then copy all terminal output and paste it to your question.

Comment: Usually messages about `[sr1]` (internal CD-ROM of modem) should not exist. Modern 16.04 system has all necessary rules  in `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules` and modem initialisation in `/usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz` (in `12d1:15d2` file). You should try  to comment your custom udev rules, reboot and test it again.

Comment: After I've modified the rules as proposed, `[sr1]` still appears

Comment: Looks like this: http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1946&view=previous

Comment: @kukulo the problem looks quite similar, but I haven't installed `wicd` at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found straightforward solution.

What if we download `usb-modeswitch-data` package from 14.04 LTS and install it on 16.04 LTS:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch-data/usb-modeswitch-data_20140327-1_all.deb
```

I tried to install this package with `dpkg -i`, but this makes `usb-modeswitch` package broken. So I decided to extract the data package manually (it stay recorded in dpkg-database as having xenial version):

```
sudo dpkg -x usb-modeswitch-data_20140327-1_all.deb /
```

Please make sure that you have uncommented your udev rules (so they stay as in 14.04 LTS) and then reboot.

Then if modem works you can pin this package versions with the following command:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-usb-modeswitch
Package: usb-modeswitch
Pin: version 2.2.5+repack0-1ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: usb-modeswitch-data
Pin: version 20151101-1
Pin-Priority: 1001
EOF
```

Don't forget to enable your rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-usb-modeswitch.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="15d2", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 15d2 -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="15d3", RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'modprobe option && echo 12d1 15d3 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id'"
```

I tested this approach with my Huawei 12d1:1446 - it does not work in normal 16.04 LTS, but works with `usb-modeswitch-data` from 14.04 LTS.

Comment: It seems like a good idea! But it doesn't work... The stick is shown as 12d1:15d3 (modem modus), so it's switched. Maybe I have do downgrade `usb-modeswitch` well?

Comment: Downgraded `usb-modeswitch` will not work on xenial, I tested this before. Did you enabled (uncommented) rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-usb-modeswitch.rules`?

Comment: Yes, I did it like you said.

Comment: You can try to purge `usb-modeswitch-data` package - so `usb-modeswitch` will be launched (I hope) from your `.rules` file.

Comment: I tried to install `usb-modeswtich` from the archive as well. So I had two old packages. But I didn't solve the problem.
If I have commented the rules, the stick isn't in modem modus, whereas if they are enabled, it is in modem modus. So maybe I have to search for a solution somewhere else?